# How to convert list like string to list of dictionary?

Tags: python

I have list like string retuned from AJAX post request:

```
["{'id': '1',  'name': 'John'}","{'id': '2',  'name': 'Paul'}"]
```

I have used `ast.literal_eval()` but raises exception:

```
 raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
> 
> ls_j = request.form['journal_to_match']\
 ls_j= ast.literal_eval(ls_j)
```

What is the best way to convert to list of dictionary?

Comment: An AJAX request likely returns JSON. Try `import json;json.loads(ls_j)`.

Comment: If you're going to use `ast.literal_eval` Don't use it on the entire list. Use it on the strings in the list. `[literal_eval(s) for s in data]`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so you hold a list of strings and want each element to evaluated to a dict?
just do the following:

```
res_list = [eval(dict_string) for dict_string in ls_j]
```

`eval()` will read any string and perform it as if a user had typed it

Comment: `eval` is not a good suggestion. It's unsafe. But `ast.literal_eval` is a safe alternative.

Comment: Thanks @NanoByte & @Jab. it works with ast.literal_eval , 


`res_list = [ast.literal_eval(dict_string) for dict_string in ls_j]`

Comment: [`why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/4985099)

Answer (score 2):

It seems your strings are JSON formatted. You could simply do:

```
import json

dict_list = [json.loads(s) for s in strings_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is JSON response you are getting from API call. You can use json library to parse the data.

```
import json
# dataList = ['{"id": "1",  "name": "John"}','{"id": "2",  "name": "Paul"}']
dataList = request.form['journal_to_match']
json_data = [json.loads(data) for data in dataList]
print(json_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```py
>>> import json

>>> ls_j = request.form['journal_to_match']
>>> [json.loads(e) for e in ls_j]
```